# how do I get a SQL 'When' clause to only return concat data if both columns are NOT NULL?

Tags: sql-server

I have the following code in SQL Server:

```
[siteWindowStart] = case
        when loc.LOCATION_TYPE_ID = '1'
        and ps.STOP_PLANNED_START_DATE is null
            then concat(pt.[TOUR_PLANNED_START_DATE], 'T', '09:00:00')
        when loc.LOCATION_TYPE_ID = '1'
        and ps.STOP_PLANNED_START_DATE is not null
            then concat(ps.STOP_PLANNED_START_DATE, 'T', '09:00:00')
        when loc.LOCATION_TYPE_ID in  ('6', '7', '8')
        and ps.STOP_REQUIRED_DELIVERY_DATE is not null
            then concat(dateadd(day, -1, ps.STOP_REQUIRED_DELIVERY_DATE), 'T' ,ps.[STOP_REQUIRED_DELIVERY_TIME])
        when loc.LOCATION_TYPE_ID in ('6', '7', '8')
        and ps.STOP_REQUIRED_DELIVERY_DATE is null
            then CONCAT(dateadd(day, -1, pt.[TOUR_PLANNED_START_DATE]), 'T', pt.[TOUR_PLANNED_START_TIME])
        else null
        end
```

For this part of the code...

```
and  ps.STOP_REQUIRED_DELIVERY_DATE is not null
            then concat(ps.STOP_REQUIRED_DELIVERY_DATE, 'T', dateadd(minute, 30, ps.[STOP_REQUIRED_DELIVERY_TIME]))
```

I need to ensure that it only returns the concat if both `ps.stop_required_delivery_date` AND `ps.stop_required_delivery_time` are both not null.

I tried adding:

```
and ps.stop_required_delivery_time is not null
```

but this simply returned the else statement which is 'NULL' !

How do I code this to only return the concat text if both columns are not null? And if one is null whilst the other is populated return

```
then concat(pt.[TOUR_PLANNED_START_DATE], 'T', dateadd(minute, 30, pt.[TOUR_PLANNED_START_TIME]))
```

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server?

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance.

Comment: I've removed the conflicting tags. [Edit] your question to retag the RDBMS you are *really* using.

Comment: @jarlh it is on sqlserver...sorry am new to this so will add a reproducible example in the future, thanks for the tip.

Comment: No problem, we are all here to learn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`IS NULL` and `IS NOT NULL` work perfectly in a `CASE` as in the following example.
I've used datatypes date and time to make it as close to your case as possible without having your table definitions and sample data.

> ```
> CREATE TABLE t ( a date, b time);
> insert into t values ('2022-01-01','10:00'),('2022-01-01',null),(null,'10:00'),(null,null);
>
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> 4 rows affected
> ```
>
> ```
> select  
>         a,
>         b,
>         case
>         when a is not null and b is not null then concat(a,'T',b)
>         when a is not null and b is null then 'a-null'
>         when a is null and b is not null then 'null-b'
>         when a is null and b is null then 'null-null'
>         else 'not possible' 
>         end "a-b"
>   from t
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> a          | b                | a-b                        
> :--------- | :--------------- | :--------------------------
> 2022-01-01 | 10:00:00.0000000 | 2022-01-01T10:00:00.0000000
> 2022-01-01 | null             | a-null                     
> null       | 10:00:00.0000000 | null-b                     
> null       | null             | null-null
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b7d22a2a44daff5a6064a9131cd6ab72)*

Comment: Thank you so much, recoded as recommended to allow for all permutations and it worked like a dream....out of  curiosity!, was or is there a shortcut in such cases for multiple permutations???

Comment: if we are always testing on 1 column we can write `case column_name when val1 then out1 when val2 then out2` if we have several conditions which should give the same output we can write `case when (a and b) or (c and d) then out1 else out2 end` but I agree with you that case tends to be long